# Does Cloud Vision API have a way to get back Key Value pair as response, like their AWS Textract counterpart?

Tags: google-cloud-vision, amazon-textract, cloud-document-ai

I need a way to access the OCR data in a Key-Value format. Does Google Cloud Vision API have a way to get back Key Value pair as response, like their AWS Textract counterpart?

We are currently getting back boundary coordinates, but that doesn't really help in the scenario we are working with.

Is there any OOB or easy configuration setting we might be overlooking?

Comment: I just answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874345/cloud-document-ai-key-value-pair-response/71603864#71603864 let me know if it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

I looked up AWS Textract and GCP has a similar product which is [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/overview). Document AI can process simple documents and it is also capable to process specific type of forms like government forms, invoices, etc.

I'm not familiar on how AWS Textract retrieves data, but the [response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) in Document AI is structured like Document -> Pages -> (Paragraphs/Lines/Block) -> Layout -> Text Anchor -> Text Segment. With this structure, the Text Segment contains `startIndex` and `endIndex`. Using these values, you can fetch the whole Paragraph/Line/Block from [Document.Text](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#FIELDS.text) and will return the actual value.

You can check a sample code implementation [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request) so you can see the flow on how Document AI.

Comment: FYI, there is an actively monitored tag for Document AI [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)