# Cloud Document AI key value pair response

Tags: cloud-document-ai

Google cloud document AI is supposed to give response in key value pair form like this.[DOC-AI console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWa9o.png)

But when we hit its api then it gives us response in json(which is obviously key value) but i want the text response as shown in the upper pic like key value pair.
The response by postman api is as follows:
[Postman Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypfCF.png)
Now here i want that text section as key value pair like against invoice id i want invoice id.

Is there is any solution regarding this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. First, please remove the information you have added in the answers section and add to your question by editing it.

Comment: The document ai response has the fields `form_fields {}`  where is located the data you mentionated, but it just indicate the position on the text, and not the value. The best ways is to send the request via the python api, then you can use the object returned properties to get the values. You can find [here a snippet in python](https://github.com/ewertonvsilva/stackoverflow/tree/main/70874345) that I have used here to test it. The result will be like: `'Invoice Number': 'IN-76889987977778', 'Due Date': 'February 22, 2022','Invoice Date': 'February 8, 2022' ... Does it help ?

Comment: @ewertonvsilva in the json response we can get that key value pair as shown on the console of google cloud in the "entities" field of the response.But as of I know that "entities" field is present in only the response of invoice parser

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling to understand this. What I did is to upload the JSON response to something like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# and inspect the document.

As you can see, in `"pages"` you can find the various `formFields` in which you can find the relevant key-value pairs.

Comment: You can check this documentation to see sample code for how to [handle the processing response for the Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables)

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this, you can get the k-v pair from  the formFields and then build the map you want

```
ProcessRequest request = ProcessRequest.newBuilder().setName(name).setRawDocument(document).build();
ProcessResponse result = client.processDocument(request);
Document documentResponse = result.getDocument();
Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Document.Page page : documentResponse.getPagesList()) {
    List<Document.Page.FormField> formFields = page.getFormFieldsList();
    for (Document.Page.FormField formField : formFields) {
        String key = formField.getFieldName().getTextAnchor().getContent();
        String value = formField.getFieldValue().getTextAnchor().getContent();
        resultMap.put(key, value);
    }
}
```